# Problems reading NfcV tag on android app

Tags: java, android, hex, byte, nfc

I'm programming an app for our guild in which we want to optimize our membership administration on our trips we're doing during the karneval in Germany.
I've completed nearly every feature but in the case 'NFC Tag Reading' I can't get any further.

The tag i need to read from is a NfcV Tag. It was implemented along with a professional reading 'computer' so we want to use them furthermore.
When i'm reading this tag with a usual NFC Reading App this is the result:

```
Tag ID (hex): e0 04 03 50 00 57 c2 a3
Tad ID (dec): -2304713467168832861
ID (reversed): -66466544411911439136
Technologies: NfcV, NdefFormatable
```

I implemented several solutions but the best I've been able to read was this:

> a3 c2 57 00 50 03 04 e0

I've found this hexID with this solution:

```
nfcv.connect();
        byte[] tagID = nfcv.getTag().getId();
        String tagInhalt = getHex(tagID);
        Log.d("Hex ID", tagInhalt);
        String message = new String(tagInhalt);
```

For the next step i want to read the US-ASCII Part. The App NFC tagInfo gives me the informations:

```
Data (US-ASCII)
Block 0: (some weird signs)
Block 1: 089
Block 2: 
Block 3:
Block 4:
Block 5:
Block 6:
Block 7:
```

Are there anny suggestions how to read the US-ASCII Part?

Comment: What's your actual question? What information do you expect? It seems that you obtained the very same information both from your app and from the "usual NFC Reading App".

Comment: Oh you're right, i'va to add some context.
Every member of our guild has its own number, i'm number 89. With the nfc tag everyone can be identified with the bought maschine scanner. 

So i'm note really sure which output can be generated but i'm expecting something like my number

89

Because on every event they've scanned my tag and knew that it was number 89. Hope this helps

Comment: Also i've installed a nfcv reading app. The results are supplemented in the origin post